# ruby on rails install help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I run this command successfully: sudo gem install rails

It outputs: Successfully installed rails-3.0.10

However, whenever I type in rails -v it shows: Rails 1.2.6

How can this be? Whenever I create a new project and do rails server, localhost:3000 doesn't work.

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu, you can follow http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/ to install rvm and rails.

Comment: Do you want two versions of rails? Or just the latest?

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that your system has rails preinstalled, and the rubygems version is not overriding it.

You might have luck installing rvm and then installing rails within an rvm gemset.